# Typescript error with angular 2 and visual studio

Tags: angular

i got some unexpected error on compile time , i am using asp.net core with angular 2 
**this is my tsconfig**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "../wwwroot/Scripts"

  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

[image]

After changing to

```
 "baseUrl": "./wwwroot/Scripts/"
```

i got this error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   TS5023  Build:Unknown compiler option 'baseUrl'.
```

please suggest me what i am doing wrong .

Comment: What version of typescript?

Comment: "typescript": "2.0.6",